# Search String and Count Occurrences of Specific Text Found Using Column Range

Tags: excel, string, count, range

Using MS Excel I would like a formula that searches and counts the number of occurrences of a specific keyword(s) contained within a string of text located in Cell A2 and matches keywords located in Column B2:B9 and return a number that matches.

Cell A2 (String of Text)
Present Address 123 Name Street, San Francisco, CA Previous Address 456 Same Street, Philadelphia, PA.

Cell B2:B9 (List of Keywords in Column)
Baltimore, MD; 
Boston, MA; 
Philadelphia, PA; 
Houston, TX ; 
Chicago, IL; 
San Francisco, CA; 
Los Angeles, CA; 
Tampa, FL

=COUNTIF(B2:B9,A2) {Returns 0}

Note: Find Matching City & State in Cell A2 that is located in Column B2:B9
Result = 2 (San Francisco, CA; Philadelphia, PA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT for cyclic calculation. The Len of A2 minus the length of A2 without any particular keyword divided by the length of that keyword is the number of times that keyword occurs in A2.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2:B9,"")))/LEN(B2:B9))
```

The above should be able to count multiple occurrences of any single keyword in A2 and provide a total count for all keywords.